# Basic Javascript help - Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a show more button to extend the div "expandable"

This code below works but works when the user clicks ANYWHERE on the document.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.expandable').animate({
      'height': '100%',
    })
})
```

This code below **should** work I believe? When the user clicks on the div "show-more-btn" but it doesn't:

```
$('#show-more-btn').click(function() {
    $('.expandable').animate({
      'height': '100%',
    })
})
```

**EDIT:** (Code from comments)

```
<div id="show-more-btn"> 
    <p>Show More</p> 
    <img src="images/show-more.png" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

There are no errors in console on load or click or anything..

Comment: syntax error? '#show-more-btn'

Comment: syntax error? `$('#show-more-btn)` => `$('#show-more-btn')`

Comment: Typo on the question. Not the code - Still not working :(

Comment: <div id="show-more-btn">

  <p>Show More</p>
  <img src="images/show-more.png" alt="" />

 </div>

No errors in console on load or click or anything..

Comment: <div class="expandable">
<div class="features">
Large amounts of content....
</div>
</div>
<div id="show-more-btn"> 
    <p>Show More</p> 
    <img src="images/show-more.png" alt="" /> 
</div>

Comment: @Help - could you post your code in a jsFiddle?

Comment: THANKS! 
So I very new to learning javascript and no my site.js did not start with $(document).ready(function(){

This solves the problem. 
Thanks to all those who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have mentioned the same code works on `$(document).click`, I assume there should be an element with `class='expandable'`. The only other issue I could see is that your code is in the `<head>` section and is not wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Wrap it like shown below: (The *event handler* should be assigned after the element is created and available)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show-more-btn').click(function() {
        $('.expandable').animate({
          'height': '100%',
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#show-more-btn').click(function () {
    $('.expandable').animate({
        'height': '100%'
    })
})
```

you missed a `'` in your selector

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCpN3/2/)

Comment: sorry i typo'd on the question - The code is not working still :(

Comment: <div id="show-more-btn">

  <p>Show More</p>
  <img src="images/show-more.png" alt="" />

 </div>

Comment: sorry <div class="expandable"> is a large div full of content above the show more button.

The height of that div is restricted and onClick I want it to expand to height 100%.

The first block of Java works perfectly only it happens when you clikc anywhere in the document, I want it to only happen when you click on the "#show-more-btn"

Comment: I added a fiddle example of it working. You must have another problem somewhere

Comment: My javascript did not start with $(document).ready(function(){
Thank you so much for your help, I am amazed with the quick help from people on here. You're great :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#show-more-btn').click(function() {
    $('.expandable').animate({
      'height': '100%'
    });
});
```

Try this : I think you missed semicolons in the end of two functions.